# Does C++17 consider two functions as overloading instead of specialization when there is ellipsis parameter in function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Let's consider two codes below;

Following code is summing all numbers given in *template parameters*, where signature of functions are equivalent; If you uncomment `template <class T, T v1> T sum1()` part, then you will get a compile error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T> T sum1() { return T{0}; }
// template <class T, T v1> T sum1() { return v1; } // Ambiguous!
template <class T, T v1, T... v2> T sum1() {
    return v1 + sum1<T, v2...>();
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << sum1<int, 1>() << '\n';
    std::cout << sum1<int, 1, 2>() << '\n';
    std::cout << sum1<int, 1, 2, 3>() << '\n';
}
```

Following code is printing all arguments given in *function signature*, where the one with variadic template has additional ellipsis parameter; No compiler error is happening.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T> void print(std::ostream &out, T value) {
    out << value << std::endl;
}

template <class T, class... Types> void print(std::ostream &out, T value, Types... values) {
    out << value << ' ';
    print(out, values...);
}

int main(void) {
    print(std::cout, 1, 2.3, "abc");
}
```

So far what I understand is, if you uncomment the `template <class T, T v1>` part then compiler will make an instantiation of `<class T, T v1>` part, but `<class T, T v1, T... v2>` will try to generate another instantiation of `<class T, T v1>`, therefore it fails.

However, it seems the same thing doesn't applies to `print` function. Is this because of additional ellipsis parameter `values`?

For your information, I used g++ 7.5 with `--std=c++17` and `-g`.

Comment: *Does C++17 consider two functions as overloading* You don't have two functions, you have two/three templates. The second and the first templates are ambiguous for `sum1<int, 1>()` call. You don't need the second temlate.

Comment: The second code is another case, they are overloaded functions, template parameters are deduced from arguments.

Comment: @273K given `print(std::cout, 1);`, both templates are a match ... I presume one of them is a _better match_?  (I don't know, but I'm guessing that's the core question here)

Comment: @273K Yeah, since compiler ignores ellipsis parameter in template arguments during deduction, it makes sense to make a compile error in the first code, However, I don't understand for the second code, if `sizeof...(values)` is zero, then wouldn't it generate second definition of `print<T>`?

Comment: If `sizeof...(values)` is zero, then `print(out);` is a failure and the rule [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) works.

Comment: @273K So that specialization for second overload function `print(out, value)` is discarded, wow.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes loosely summarizing, the best matching template match wins. The template with the pack has 3 parameters (last one being the pack), but there is already a template with 2 parameters that matches so that one is considered.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thank you!  I was hanging on to this question.  Maybe paste that into an answer?

Comment: @DrewDormann Stupid thing is I know this rule exists, I currently cannot find a reference to it on cppreference or in the standard. Which I think is needed to make it a real answer